# Data not being passed in Navigator.pop

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to pass data from a screen with navigator.pop, it shows the result in the second screen, but in the first screen the data is always null. I tried some things on it but didn't work.

Here I'm calling the second screen:

```
     onPressed: () async {
    final result = await push(context, PickMaterialPage());
    print("Result $result");
  },
```

In this one is when I want to pass the data for the first screen with navigator.pop, It's an object.

```
  Card card(int index, context) {
RequisicaoMaterial material = materiais[index];
try {
  return Card(
      color: Colors.grey[300],
      elevation: 6.0,
      margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 10.0),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => pop(context, material),
        child: CustomListTile(
          Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
          '${material.codMaterial} - ${material.nomeMaterial}',
          '${material.codUnidade} - ${material.sigla} - ${material.classificacao}',
          null,
        ),
      ));
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

I don't want to use constructor in this one, i needed to make it simple and only get the picked data to show in the first screen.

output `$result = null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PUSH THE SCREEN**

```
  String result = await Navigator.push(
   context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (_) => AddTenantToRoomFlyPage(),
      ),
    );
```

**POP THE SCREEN**

```
Navigator.pop(context, "RETURN VALUE");
```

Comment: I don't why it worked, well thanks, but I'm doing it with push and pop. The only difference is that I have a class that makes my calls smaller instead of writing the full code.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
onTap: () => Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => PickMaterialPage(),
    )).then((value) => print(value)),
```